# Multiple UITableViewController and one model class to hold data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble deciding.
I created a model class, and another one as a singleton,
the singleton uses a NSMutableArray and returns a NSArray as a copy.
One of the UITableViewController will show the array of data.
The question is, if I want to show different data on each UITableViewController should i create multiple arrays and methods that save and edit the arrays or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your UITableViewDataSource methods, you can decide what information to return based on which TableView is calling the method. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //Check which tableview is calling
    if (tableview == self.tableView1) {
        // Return the number of sections for each possible Table
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }  
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
// If you're serving data from an array, return the length of the array:
    if (tableview == self.tableView1) {
        // Return the number of sections for each possible Table
        return [dataArray1 count];
    } else {
        return [dataArray2 count];
    }  
}
```

And the same for any DataSource/Delegate methods you may need to implement.

Hope that helps!!